# Core Data is creating NULL values

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have a pretty simply piece of save code that goes as follows:

```
 SOModule* newModule = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SOModule" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
 newModule.name = self.tf_name.text;
 newModule.ip = self.tf_ip.text;
 newModule.port = self.tf_port.text;
 newModule.user = self.tf_user.text;
 newModule.password = self.tf_pass.text;
 newModule.created = [NSDate date];
 NSError* error = [NSError alloc]init];
 [self.managedObjectContext save:&error]; //doesn't say anything when NULL stuff is created
```

The Managed Object Context is created by using this Core Data method:

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext
{
    return [(SOAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]managedObjectContext];
}
```

The problem is that I am getting NULL values at random times when  ever I try to save the text fields in the `SOModule` object. Here's an example I pulled from inspecting my Core Data database:

[image]

As you can see, there is no recognizable pattern of the NULL values appearing, while the save function is being called in the same way every time. Also, just to clarify, I just started to put `test8` multiple times because I got tired haha, but I haven't implemented checking for duplicates yet, so this shouldn't matter.

Any help would be awesome, this is driving my nuts!

~Carpetfizz

Comment: Put some logging code in to display the objects name just before save is called. Seems you are getting null values back from your UI or somehow you skip setting the attributes.

Comment: Thanks, turns out I was getting some junk from the UI!

Comment: Please change your comment to an answer and accept it so the question shows as closed.

Comment: Agree with @HalMueller. Could you reply to your own answer indicating the problem/solution you found in order that other people can see it? Thanks.

Comment: Also: `NSError* error = [NSError alloc]init];` is incorrect, just use `NSError* error;`

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug the program I had a little method that looped through values and printed them on the screen. The problem was that I was initializing the loop iterator as a managed object context subclass. That was being added every time the loop added, and that object would be added to the save queue. When the save was called at any time, the managed object context subclass would save.